# jquerymobile background popup disable touch

Tags: jquery-mobile, background, dialog, popup

sorry if my english bad
when I create a dialog popup with jquerymobile, I get a transparent background, but when I touched it, causing the closure of the dialogue, how do I make the dialog will not close when I touch the background until I touch the cancel button?
thank you

for example login form dialog button in demos jquerymobile
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior of a jQM popup is by design.

It looks like instead of a popup you just need to use a jQM [modal dialog](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can add data-dismissible="false" attribute as it describes in the document: 
http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-dismissible